# Get data from table row on click

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

Here I have an table: http://jsbin.com/IhEmetI/8 built with Google visualization api and here is the code: http://jsbin.com/IhEmetI/8/edit

CODE:

```
 var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'Table',
          'containerId': 'chart2',
          'cssClassNames': 'cssClassNames',
          'options': {
        cssClassNames: cssClassNames,
        allowHtml: true
    }
        });

        // Create a dashboard
        new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
            // Establish bindings, declaring the both the slider and the category
            // picker will drive both charts.
            bind([slider, categoryPicker, stringFilter], [pie, table], [stringFilter, table]).
            // Draw the entire dashboard.
            draw(data, {'allowHtml':true, 'cssClassNames': 'cssClassNames'});      }
```

Now I want to get data Row when I click on some table row? 
How I can do that?

How I can do this with javascript?
Is there some build in google API function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a 'select' handler for the Table.  Working with a ChartWrapper, the syntax for this is a little different than normal (as you have to wrap the event handler for the Table inside a `'ready'` event handler for the wrapper).  It works like this:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(table.getChart(), 'select', function () {
        var selection = table.getChart().getSelection();
        // iterate over all selected rows
        for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
            // do something with selection[i].row
        }
    });
});
```

You have to iterate over all selected rows, since users can select multiple rows from the table.

Comment: ok, I implement this into my code: google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(table.getChart(), 'ready', function () {
        var selection = table.getChart().getSelection();
        // iterate over all selected rows
        for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
            // do something with selection[i].row
        }
    });
}); http://jsbin.com/IhEmetI/9/edit, but dont work ... what I need is to to put all values from table to input field and to change it and update my database

Comment: You need to add the event handlers after you create the `table` ChartWrapper and before you draw the dashboard.

Comment: yes I add here but how to show values from row to input fields, to allow to users change values in input, and to update the database ... also now i get error in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined

Comment: You problably are getting that error because you put the handler in the wrong place - as I mentioned above, it needs to be between where you cerate the table and where you draw the dashboard.  You can get the data from the DataTable via `data.getValue(row, column)`.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/IhEmetI/11/edit I got this when I check in browser console: Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined 9:125
data.getValue(1,1);
ReferenceError: data is not defined
google.visualization.data.getValue(1,1);
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getValue'

Comment: I don't get that error on http://jsbin.com/IhEmetI/11/edit.  I did notice that I made a mistake in the internal event listener - it should be `'select'` not `'ready'`; I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46364/discussion-between-asgallant-and-mikimrki)

Comment: Here  is really good staff and easy t understand, but on my example I can't call DATA ... etc. data.InserRow, data.getNumberOfRows(); ... screenshhot: http://i.imgur.com/0GULBZ5.png, I get error data is not defined ... ??? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use data.getFormattedValue(selection[i].row, column)
For some reason, getValue always returns 0 for integer columns and empty for strings!